# Using Gsub to get matched strings in R - regular expression

Tags: regex, gsub

I am trying to extract words after the first space using

> species<-gsub(".* ([A-Za-z]+)", "\1", x=genus)

This works fine for the other rows that have two words, however row [9] "Eulamprus tympanum marnieae" has 3 words and my code is only returning the last word in the string "marnieae". How can I extract the words after the first space so I can retrieve "tympanum marnieae" instead of "marnieae" but have the answers stored in one variable called >species.

> genus

[9] "Eulamprus tympanum marnieae"

Comment: Please post your input so we can be sure we're providing the proper answer.

Comment: genusnew<-gsub("([A-Za-z]+)", "\\1", x=genus)  to retrieve first word in string.

Comment: species<-gsub(".* ([A-Za-z]+)", "\\1", x=genus) to retrieve second word in string. For row [9] it retrieved the third word in string but not the second

Comment: That's not your input; that's your code, and it was already included in the original question. Please show the actual text you are working on, or at least a portion of it. All you provided was an example of a line that wasn't matching properly, but it would be more useful to see the whole thing in context.

Comment: >genus
 [1] "Bellatorias obiri"           "Caretta caretta"            
 [3] "Cyclodomorphus praealtus"    "Dermochelys coriacea"       
 [5] "Egernia stokesii badia"      "Elseya lavarackorum"        
 [7] "Elusor macrurus"             "Eulamprus leuraensis"       
 [9] "Eulamprus tympanum marnieae" "Lepidochelys olivacea"      
[11] "Lerista allanae"             "Liopholis guthega"          
[13] "Liopholis slateri slateri"   "Lucasium occultum"          
[15] "Tiliqua adelaidensis"        "Tympanocryptis pinguicolla"

Comment: >genusnew
 [1] "obiri"        "caretta"      "praealtus"    "coriacea"    
 [5] "badia"        "lavarackorum" "macrurus"     "leuraensis"  
 [9] "marnieae"     "olivacea"     "allanae"      "guthega"     
[13] "slateri"      "occultum"     "adelaidensis" "pinguicolla"

Comment: > species
 [1] "obiri"        "caretta"      "praealtus"    "coriacea"    
 [5] "badia"        "lavarackorum" "macrurus"     "leuraensis"  
 [9] "marnieae"     "olivacea"     "allanae"      "guthega"     
[13] "slateri"      "occultum"     "adelaidensis" "pinguicolla"

Comment: Editing that into the question with code formatting would make it much more readable. Anyway, the following pattern should capture any number of words after the first: `"[A-Za-z]+ ([A-Za-z ]+)"`. If you only ever expect to see a maximum of 2 words in the species name, you can use `"[A-Za-z]+ ([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)?)"`. Let me know if that works for you and I'll add it as an answer below.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original pattern didn't work because the subpattern `[A-Za-z]+` doesn't match spaces, and therefore will only match a single word.

You can use the following pattern to match any number of words (other than 0) after the first, within double quotes:

`"[A-Za-z]+ ([A-Za-z ]+)"` https://regex101.com/r/p6ET3I/1

https://regex101.com/r/p6ET3I/2

This is a relatively simple, but imperfect, solution. It will also match trailing spaces, or just one or more spaces after the first word even if a second word doesn't exist. `"Eulamprus      "` for example will successfully match the pattern, and return 5 spaces. You should only use this pattern if you trust your data to be properly formatted.

A more reliable approach would be the following:

`"[A-Za-z]+ ([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*)"`

https://regex101.com/r/p6ET3I/3

This pattern will capture one word (following the first), followed by any number of addition words (including 0), separated by spaces.

However, from what I remember from biology class, species are only ever comprised of one or two names, and never capitalized. The following pattern will reflect this format:

`"[A-Za-z]+ ([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)?)"`

https://regex101.com/r/p6ET3I/4

Comment: Thank you so so much, this is a brilliantly detailed answer and I have found this to be very helpful :-)